# Add number or character at the end of a string based on condition using R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have data that look like this:

```
a <- c("t_1", "t_2", "100", "200")
b <- c(100, 200, 300, 277)

dat <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I want to make column `a` into a numeric variable. What I want is to first add three `0`'s behind the first digit for the values starting with `t_` and then remove the `t_` and convert the column to a numerical data type.

The result should be:

```
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  1000   100
2  2000   200
3   100   300
4   200   277
```

It's important to add the `0`'s before removing the `t_`s since the real data set looks somewhat different.

A dplyr solution would be nice!

Comment: When someone says "It's important to ... since the real data set looks somewhat different" that is a red flag for the solution not working. Why not share what the real data actually look like?

Comment: I just want to keep the example simple. I understand that it's not preferable to link to a csv file or something. The data looks pretty much the same but with a lot more rows and values which means that some values in column a could be t_50 and another value could be 50 and I don't want those values to collide.

Comment: The explanation you gave in the comments is probably enough for next time. Cheers.

Comment: I'll remember that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `readr::parse_number`:

```
library(dplyr);library(readr);library(stringr)
dat %>%
  mutate(a = case_when(str_detect(a,"t_") ~ parse_number(a) * 1000,
                       TRUE ~ parse_number(a)))
     a   b
1 1000 100
2 2000 200
3  100 300
4  200 277
```

The benefit of `case_when` is that it's easy to add the millions case, IE `str_detect(a,"m_") ~ parse_number(a) * 1000000`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slight modification from what dear Mr. @Ian Campbell suggested. I think `str_pad` function can also be come in handy for this purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>%
  mutate(a = ifelse(str_detect(a, "t_"), str_pad(str_remove(a, "t_"), 
                                                 4, "right", "0"), a), 
         a = as.numeric(a))

     a   b
1 1000 100
2 2000 200
3  100 300
4  200 277
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this without a condition statement.  Here, we use `str_replace` to match the 't_', capture the digits (`\\d+`) as a group (`(...)`), replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group followed by three zeros and convert to `numeric` class with `as.numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(a = as.numeric(str_replace(a, 't_(\\d+)', '\\1000'))) 
#     a   b
#1 1000 100
#2 2000 200
#3  100 300
#4  200 277
```

Comment: Oh man! I just carefully followed the description and just never thought there could be easier ways to do it. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

The most frugal solution, it seems, is this:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(a = sub('t_(\\d+)', '\\1000', a),
         a = as.numeric(a))
```

Here, `\\1000` is in fact not the number `1000` preceded by `\\` but a special regular expression syntax called backreference `\\1`, which 'remembers' the part in parentheses in the pattern argument, namely `(\\d+)`, which matches one or more consecutive digits. The backreference repeats these digits and the three `000` following it are indeed the literal three `0`you want to append.

Comment: This is a really nice solution!